# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. Is it error with the xml format?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xmlreader

Im having a problem with reading my xml with an error of `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,position 1.`

This is my code below:

```
string soapmessage = response.Content;

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(soapmessage);  //loading soap message as string 

            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
```

below attached my XML response
[image]

Comment: How certain are you that `soapmessage` *really* contains the XML you expect? Have you tried logging it? (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML rather than XmlDocument where you can - it's a much nicer API.)

Comment: I have check it and it does contain the xml since before the line of code ill check the response is successful or not and i also print the soapmessage on console but u didnt include that line. Ill try to check on using LINQ. Thank you very much. @Jon Skett